# Is a "Zone" Large Format Camera with gold plating legit?

Tags: large-format, ebay

Has anyone heard of the brand "Zone", who makes large format cameras? I've been looking into buying a 4x5 large-format camera, and have been digging through eBay items. I came across this one:

[NEW ~ Zone VI 4x5 Large Format Field Camera RARE MINT](http://cgi.ebay.com/NEW-Zone-VI-4x5-Large-Format-Field-Camera-RARE-MINT-/300459401266?pt=Film_Cameras&hash=item45f4c6a032)

It looks nice...however I am curious about the "Gold Plated Hardware" comment. Seems a little sketchy for a $1200 camera...a Linhof costs some five times as much, and it looks a lot less pretty. Is this thing legit? Is "Zone" a viable brand, or should I stick with the well-known brands like Linhof, Wista, Tachihara, etc.?

Comment: man... I'm happy with my Bush Pressman, 18 film holders and 3 (90, 137, 210) lenses... all in I've spent less than $400.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The brand is actually "Zone VI" and yes, it's a real, legitimate LF camera. Here's a [blurb](http://www.largeformatphotography.info/zoneVI.html) on that camera from [largeformatphotography.info](http://www.largeformatphotography.info/) (which has a lot of good info on various large format stuff).

No idea on the gold plating, through.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Sounds like the Zone VI is one to avoid, based on the reviews. Sounds like the gold plating is real as well, however it seems to be very thin and flakes off easily.

Comment: I've purchased Zone Vi equipment and been delighted with the quality. I've bought their photographic paper (graded) a focussing cloth (big, and completely opaque with black on one side and white on the other. (My LF camera was a Deardorf 8x10 field camera but I thought their 4x5s were well made too.) My experience was dealing with Fred Picker although I don't know who's there now.

Answer (score 3):

I have a ZoneVI camera and it isn't gold plated (I wish). As pretty as it looks it is brass.  If you know of anyone looking to buy one mine is for sale.  I am trading in my carefree large format days for babies and bottles!